# How to synchronize two ngx-datatable data sorting

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I built a shared component that uses `<ngx-datatable>` inside the component and passes all the data inputs to get it working. Everything works as expected.

The problem is I have a request to synchronize the sorting of the two data tables when the user tries to sort on either data table.

**Here's my two data tables**

```
<!-- Next Action: Data Table -->
<app-data-table #nextActionTable
    *ngIf="nextActionRowData && nextActionRowData.length"
    class="review-queue__table"
    title="Next Action"
    [theme]="DataTableTheme.Red"
    [rowData]="nextActionRowData$ | async"
    [columnData]="nextActionColumnData"
    [columnMode]="ColumnMode.Flex"
    [horizontalScroll]="true"
    headerHeight="auto"
    [footerHeight]="0"
    rowHeight="auto"
    [rowsPerPage]="5"
    (reorder)="onReorder($event)"
    (sort)="onSort($event)">
</app-data-table>

<!-- Request Queue: Data Table -->
<app-data-table #normalRequestTable
    class="review-queue__table"
    title="Request Queue"
    [theme]="DataTableTheme.Blue"
    [rowData]="requestQueueRowData$ | async"
    [columnData]="requestQueueColumnData"
    [columnMode]="ColumnMode.Flex"
    [horizontalScroll]="true"
    headerHeight="auto"
    [footerHeight]="0"
    rowHeight="auto"
    [rowsPerPage]="10"
    (reorder)="onReorder($event)"
    (sort)="onSort($event)">
</app-data-table>
```

**Here's the sorting function.**

```
/** On Sort */
public onSort(event: any): void {
    const sortObj: SortPropDir = event?.sorts[0];

    this.nextActionRowData = [...this.sortTableData(sortObj, this.nextActionRowData)];
    this.requestQueueRowData = [...this.sortTableData(sortObj, this.requestQueueRowData)];

    console.log(`Priority Table Sort: ${sortObj?.dir}`, this.nextActionRowData);
    console.log(`Normal Table Sort: ${sortObj?.dir}`, this.requestQueueRowData);
}
```

The console logs the correctly sorted row data, but the view fails to update the table that wasn't interacted with. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your datasource (I hope).

```
[rowData]="requestQueueRowData$ | async"
```

and

```
[rowData]="nextActionRowData$ | async"
```

this is Observables, but in the sort function, you are sorting an array.
Make manual subscribe to those Observables and result set to [rowData], like this:

```
[rowData]="requestQueueRowData"
[rowData]="nextActionRowData"
```